# what's wrong with the code

Tags: php

I'm very new to php. I'm reading a book having an example about while loop:

```
<html>
<body>
<table border="0" cellpadding="3">
<tr>
<td bgcolor="#CCCCCC" align="center">Distance</td>
<td bgcolor="#CCCCCC" align="center">Cost</td>
</tr>
<?

  $distance = 50;
  while ($distance <= 250) {
  echo "<tr>
    <td align=\"right\">".$distance."</td>
    <td align=\"right\">".($distance / 10)."</td>
    </tr>\n";

  $distance += 50;
}

?>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's the result when I run this code on Apache web server:

```
\n"; $distance += 50; } ?>
Distance     Cost
".$distance."   ".($distance / 10)."
```

I don't know why the value of `$distance` is not printed. Could you help me fix it? Thank you very much!

Comment: off-topic: use CSS rather than inline attributes, unless they're `[class]`es or `[id]`s.

Comment: PHP doesn't seems to be interpreted. Is `mod_php` enabled? If so, I think @Quentin is right: Do not use short tags!

Comment: Take a look at the "Related" column on the right of StackOverflow. Please rewrite your question's title, as it is completely meaningless now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Start a code block with `<?php`, not `<?`. [Do not use short tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200640/are-php-short-tags-acceptable-to-use).

(If your book is giving PHP examples with short tags, and HTML examples with `bgcolor` then I recommend getting a newer one).

Comment: I used to change <? to <?php but nothing happened. Now It works -> weird!! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
<?php ?>
```

rather than

```
<? ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

First, the php code should start with "`<?php`", please replace the "`<?`" with "`<?php`". Then, the file should be saved to ".php" file.

Answer (score 0):

When in HTML-Context (i.e. you are writing a html-page) it is more clear to use the template-style:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <table border="0" cellpadding="3">
            <tr>
                <td bgcolor="#CCCCCC" align="center">Distance</td>
                <td bgcolor="#CCCCCC" align="center">Cost</td>
            </tr>
            <?php for($distance = 50; $distance <= 250; $distance += 50): ?>
            <tr>
                <td align="right"><?php echo $distance ?></td>
                <td align="right"><?php echo $distance / 10 ?></td>
            </tr>
            <?php endfor ?>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is also compatible with wysiwyg-editors like dreamweaver.